# Using \verbatiminput on filenames with underscores

Tags: verbatim, include, external-files, typewriter

I'm trying to include some source files using `\verbatiminput{}`. Some of these filenames have underscores in them. This works fine by default. But if I try to include the `underscore` package so that I can use underscores in text and within `\texttt{}`, suddenly my `verbatim input` stops working (it tries to read the file specified by the name before the underscore, and it just prints out the text after the underscore). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of the [`underscore` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/underscore) states that `_` must be avoided in file names.  However, if you do need to use an `_` in the file name, there is the `[strings]` package option which along with the `\UnderscoreCommands` can be used to specify a list of commands where an `_` is needed.

Below, I have added the command `\verbatiminput` to the this list -- the others are directly from the documentation.  Note that this list **must** be defined **before** the package is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\UnderscoreCommands}{\do\verbatiminput%
\do\citeNP \do\citeA \do\citeANP \do\citeN \do\shortcite%
\do\shortciteNP \do\shortciteA \do\shortciteANP \do\shortciteN%
\do\citeyear \do\citeyearNP%
}
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}

\begin{document}
\texttt{Am going to include the file a_b here}% This still produces the correct output
\verbatiminput{a_b}
\end{document}
```