# "! Missing $ inserted." while including graphics (file/dir names with white space)

Tags: graphics

Solved!

EDIT (changed source to Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./obrazki/} }
\usepackage{epstopdf} %eps

\begin{document}
\graphicspath{ {./obrazki/wyniki_eksperymentu/Wyniki przegladu_EMG/wykresy/} }

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=10cm]{Najlepszych_30_kombinacji} % Error here
    \caption{Najlepsze kombinacje łańcuchów algorytmów ekstrakcji i klasyfikatorów}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for replies. I was so fixed on underscores problem, that i didn't noticed white space in dir path :D

Since i can't give you any reward (only comments - no answers) :

"Best Answer Award" goes to **Henri Menke** for package which solves problem:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

Second award goes to **cfr** for spotting source of the problem :)

Comment: Can you post a Minimal Working Example? That is, something people can compile to reproduce the problem? You seem to have two inconsistent \graphicspath calls. Is that intentional? Is the second intended to override the first? Have you tried removing the space from the components of the path? Those can often cause problems.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's the underscores in the filename. Rename the file.

Comment: Or rather, rework your filesystem to avoid underscores.  A `-` works just as well, and is easier to type.  But if you can't or would rather not, try escaping the underscores: `\_`. I haven't tested this, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58689 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69142 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29161 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632

Comment: Related: The [`grffile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package by Heiko Oberdiek fixes many problems regarding inclusion of graphics, such as utf-8 encoded file names of multiple dots in file names.